# How to show calculated values in NSTableView?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have an NSTableView that binds via an NSArrayController to an NSMutableArray of NSString's.

There's also a TextView in the same window. What I want to do is display a number of occurrences of each NSString in the NSTableView.

I've thought of a way to do this, but that doesn't look elegant way of doing this:

Inherit from NSString and define new method that performs a search in predefined object (NSTextView) and returns the number of occurrences.

I'm guessing there must be a more natural way of achieving the same result?

EDIT:

Sorry, should have clarified. NSSMutableArray is an array of NSObjects that have an NSString property. I suppose I could define an extra method (findAllOccurencesOfString:inString:) which would return a number. But the question is how do I bind to this function and in that binding how to I pass a var (pointer to textField)??

Comment: So, you have a text view, and you want a table view which has a row for each different word in the text view, together with a count of the number of times that word appears?

Comment: yes, that's correct, but the words in tableview are not necessarily from the textview, user types them in manually. (BTW, I've added a method that does a lookup 'findAllOccurencesIn:(NSString *)text' but I don't know how to reference it. Simply putting in 'Model Key Path' doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to have a `wordCount` (read only) property on whatever objects are in your table data source, this will have to call your new method internally using the object's own string value, as you can't pass parameters in bindings (unless they've changed, I haven't used bindings for a while as I've been concentrating on iOS). Then bind to this property for the column in the table. Presumably you don't need to pass the pointer to the textfield as there is only one?

Comment: woohoo! this worked. Thanks!! I declared a static var in the .m that implements my array objects. that var points to textview and is set in awakefromnib of the document class. now i just need to figure out how to continuously update the list while user is editing the text.

Comment: although it seemed to work initially, it appears that this is not really working - it breaks when i open multiple windows. here's why: i defined a class method that sets a pointer to a textview when nib loads. that's ok if there's only one window. next window will do exactly the same, and so overwrite what the first window set. going back to the first window and app crashes (obviously, it's looking now at the 2nd window textview element)

Comment: I'd start a new question with your new problem.

Comment: sure, just started a new one here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7704345/how-to-access-nsdocument-object-from-another-object-held-in-nsmutablearray