# How to access NSDocument object from another object held in NSMutableArray?

Tags: cocoa, nsdocument

This is really an extension of [How to show calculated values in NSTableView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510819/how-to-show-calculated-values-in-nstableview/7511512)

**The problem**:

I have an NSDocument class that contains two properties: `text` (NSString) and `phrases` (NSMutableArray of NSObjects with NSString in them).
In the Doc NIB file I have a TextView (to display phrases) with two columns. First column is bound to an ArrayController and displays NSString. That works ok.
I want to count the number of NSString occurrences in `text` and display that in the second column.

**What I tried**:

Define a static var in my NSObject that would point to a TextView. Once the NIB is loaded it would set this static var to a TextView that contains the `text` string.

This works OK if I open a single window. But if I try opening multiple windows, the static var would get updated with the new instances of TextView (from other windows). Obviously this breaks everything.

**Question**:

How do I access `text` from each of the NSObject? In other words, the object diagram is NSDocument --(contains one)--> NSMutableArray --(contains multiple)--> NSObject, so how do I get to NSDocument from NSObject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of an array of strings, use an array of dictionaries:

```
    NSDictionary *entry = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                          thePhrase, @"phrase",
                                          theCount, @"count",
                                          nil];
    [theArray addObject:entry];
```

Bind to `arrangedObjects.phrase` and `arrangedObjects.count`.

Alternatively, you could create a `Phrase` class which contains the phrase, a reference to the document, and code to calculate the count.

Comment: well I already have a custom class that has an NSstring in it. I just found it hard to assign a document to it every time it is created (user inserts new entry, or document is loaded). I have a code that does that in two places, WindowDidLoad iterates through all Phrase objects and assigns TextView to each. And in insertObject I have a similar action that assigns TextView to every new object. It works, but just feels wrong. So I was wondering if there's a more elegant solution.

Comment: Instead of having a phrase know about the text view, have it know about the document, and ask the document for its text. And you can set a phrase's document pointer in `Phrase -init` instead of `windowDidLoad`. For some background on just the kind of questions you're asking, take a look at the Model–View–Controller pattern: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH6-SW1

Comment: yeah that makes sense. I tried that, but somehow I've failed to access the NSString that was (still is) bound to NSTextView. I think the problem is that I'm using the wrong type here. Once loaded from a file the actual object is not NSString (gdb says it's NSConcreteMutableData). TextView is ok with that, but not my search method which expects string. atm i use [textview string] to get to it, but i suppose i need to bind to a different type here.

Comment: Got it. How are you loading the file now? You could try `NSString *string = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:dataObject]`

Comment: Here's what I do now: `- (BOOL)readFromData:(NSData *)data ofType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError
{
    NSKeyedUnarchiver *unarchiver;
    unarchiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:data];    
    [self setPhrases:[unarchiver decodeObjectForKey:@"phrases"]];
    [self setExcerptText:[unarchiver decodeObjectForKey:@"excerptText"]];
    [unarchiver finishDecoding];
    [unarchiver release];
    return YES;
}
`

Comment: just like: `NSKeyedArchiver *archiver;
    NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData data];
    archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:data];
    [archiver encodeObject:[self excerptText] forKey:@"excerptText"];
    [archiver encodeObject:[self phrases] forKey:@"phrases"];
    [archiver finishEncoding];
    [archiver release];
    return data;
`

Comment: Try logging `[self excerptText]` before you save. Probably it's an NSMutableData instead of an NSMutableString.

Comment: Yup, seems to be, I'm getting `CLASS: NSConcreteMutableData` if I log `[excerptText class]`. What's the best type to use with NSTextView? I naively assumed NSString, but now looking around it seems not the best choice, should it be mutable data? in Apple's doc they use `NSAttributedString`.

Comment: argh, I really should do more reading. Found this http://pseudofish.com/blog/2005/06/15/binding-to-a-nstextview/. Then realised that "Value" in NSTextView actually has 4 options. And the one I picked (no idea why though) was "Data" hence the excerptText was set to NSConcreteMutableData on load!

Comment: So the textview was reading the string, turning it into a data and then replacing the string with a data. Awesome.